# Add "not a good example" to my profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, profile-page, voting

The most interesting feedback is "not a good example", where if I get voted as such I could go clarify or even delete my example question, nevertheless, there's not a good way to track it.

Can you add it to my profile, next to the other 2 kind of votes?

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/area51c.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/area51c.png)

Edit: I think it would help to add it to the summary screen also, here:

[alt text http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/area51c2.png](http://www.juanformoso.com.ar/images/area51c2.png)

Please implement it, I see my reputation getting hit and would like to clean up bad questions but I'm unable to find them easily (without going through all)

**EDIT:** This, along with other information (like +5 for referrals and commitments that go through) was implemented.

To make it perfect though, we still have the "**+5 for commitment to your proposals**" missing, I update my feature request to request this.

Comment: +1 I'd really like to see this implemented. It's good to know when one of your questions is doing bad so you can quickly delete it and propose a new one.

Comment: this exists now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was implemented a while back, but we had forgotten (until now) to mark your [feature-request] as [status-completed].

Answer (score 1):

This is cumbersomely viewable through the [reputation audit](http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation):

```
-- 2010-06-06 rep +30   = 234       
 20     4082 (5)
 3      4250 (5)
 22     4490 (-2)             # this is a "bad example" vote
 2      4489 (5)
 2      4492 (5)
-- 2010-06-07 rep +18   = 252
```

Comment: good fix while we wait for the head honchos

Comment: @Juan: You're a programmer, you can write a short script to translate those into links. ;)  But yes, I thought it worth posting as a workaround; I obviously can't change how Area 51 works.