# A pair of changes, to NaGE viewing and example deletion, that might encourage elimination of weak examples

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Proposal:

1. Give users a view that ranked their question examples by the number of NaGE votes received (cf. [*Add “not a good example” to my profile* proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52725/add-not-a-good-example-to-my-profile)), and
2. Let reputation be immediately recovered from NaGE votes on deletion of questions.

This would, I think, both encourage the withdrawal of weak question examples and encourage more application of NaGE votes to weak questions.  If both these things happened, then the list of question examples would correspond more closely with the list of question examples deserving consideration.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52725/add-not-a-good-example-to-my-profile

Comment: sorry, my bad...

Comment: I like it.  The biggest problem with the original system wasn't the number of votes, it was the number of *questions*.  Limiting questions is fine, but encouraging people to delete them is even better.